# Sqlite table has no column named

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-studio

I am new in android development and i am working on a simple task. I have a  database class as:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDB";
// Accounts table name
private static final String TABLE_ACCOUNTS = "Accounts";
// Account Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "NameAndSurname";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
private static final String KEY_AGE = "Age";
private static final String KEY_TOD = "TypeOfDiabetes";
private static final String KEY_GENDER = "Gender";
private static final String KEY_HEIGHT = "Height";
private static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "Weight";

public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_ACCOUNTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ACCOUNTS + "("

            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PASSWORD + "TEXT,"
            + KEY_AGE + "INTEGER,"
            + KEY_TOD + "TEXT,"
            + KEY_GENDER + "TEXT,"
            + KEY_HEIGHT + "INTEGER,"
            + KEY_WEIGHT + "INTEGER"
            +")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ACCOUNTS_TABLE);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ACCOUNTS);
// Creating tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addAccount(Account account) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID,account.getId());
    values.put(KEY_NAME, account.getNameAndSurname());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, account.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, account.getPassword());
    values.put(KEY_AGE, account.getAge());
    values.put(KEY_TOD , account.getTypeOfDiabetes());
    values.put(KEY_GENDER , account.getGender());
    values.put(KEY_HEIGHT , account.getHeight());
    values.put(KEY_WEIGHT , account.getWeight());
// Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_ACCOUNTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
// Getting one Account
public Account getAccount(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ACCOUNTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL , KEY_PASSWORD , KEY_AGE, KEY_TOD, KEY_GENDER,  KEY_HEIGHT, KEY_WEIGHT }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    Account acc = new Account(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), //id
            cursor.getString(1),    //name
            cursor.getString(2),    //mail
            cursor.getString(3),    //pass
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)),  //age
            cursor.getString(5),    //TOD
            cursor.getString(6),    //gender

            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)), //Height
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8))); //Weight

 // return Account
    return acc;
}
// Getting All Accounts
public List<Account> getAllAccounts() {
    List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<Account>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ACCOUNTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Account account = new Account();
            account.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            account.setNameAndSurname(cursor.getString(1));
            account.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
            account.setPassword(cursor.getString(3));
            account.setAge(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
            account.setTypeOfDiabetes(cursor.getString(5));
            account.setGender(cursor.getString(6));

            account.setHeight(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)));
            account.setWeight(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)));
    // Adding account to list
            accountList.add(account);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return account list
    return accountList;
}

// Getting accounts Count
public int getAccountsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ACCOUNTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();
// return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

// Updating an account
public int updateAccount(Account account) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, account.getNameAndSurname());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL,account.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD,account.getPassword());
    values.put(KEY_AGE,account.getAge());
    values.put(KEY_TOD,account.getTypeOfDiabetes());
    values.put(KEY_GENDER,account.getGender());

    values.put(KEY_HEIGHT,account.getHeight());
    values.put(KEY_WEIGHT,account.getWeight());
// updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_ACCOUNTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(account.getId())});
}
// Deleting an account
public void deleteAccount(Account account) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_ACCOUNTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(account.getId()) });
    db.close();
}
}
```

and in my main activity:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
        // Inserting Account/Rows
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addAccount(new Account(1, "Admin", "admin@admin.com", "admin", 23,  "Type 1","Male", 180, 70));
        // Reading all accounts
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all accounts..");
        List<Account> accounts = db.getAllAccounts();
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            String log = "Id: " + account.getId() + " ,Name: " + account.getNameAndSurname();
        // Writing accounts to log
            Log.d("Account: : ", log);
        }
        TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        tx.setText(db.getAccount(1).getNameAndSurname());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        String log = e.toString();
        Log.d("ERROR: ", e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

I am getting error as;

table Accounts has no column named Gender

Error inserting Gender=Male TypeOfDiabetes=Type 1 id=1 Email=admin@admin.com NameAndSurname=Admin Weight=70 Height=180 Age=23 Password=admin

and

no such column: Password

Answer (score 0):

Error:
no space between a variable definiton and their  type specification.

CREATE_ACCOUNTS_TABLE
Error   KEY_GENDER + "TEXT,".
No Error KEY_GENDER + " TEXT,".

In Order to Continue , uninstall the apps. because the installed database does not meet the required definition.